# Enemy difficulty scaling in Fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

Does enemies difficulty scale as you level up?

This seems like it would mean I should invest in combat perks in the early portion of the game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes they do scale but this seems to only impact areas you've not visited before.

How did I test? Increased my level to 200 and stomped on all of the level 10 enemies for a bit, then moved to a new area I hadn't been to before, encountered a level 201 legendary and ran out of ammo before I could take him down.

Comment: Aren't Bethesda games notorious for not handling level-relatedconsole commands properly, specifically when it comes to world scaling?

Comment: Skyrim featured a system which, to my knowledge, fixed enemies in locations you have visited to remain at that level and had enemy scaling limited by a minimum and maximum level for every location which then got determined when player visited said location for the first time (in other words, a location could be set to contain enemies of levels between 10 to 20. If player of level 5 entered the location, enemies would be at level 10. They would be level 12 for level 12 player and level 20 for level 30 player). In other words, your experiment didn't prove much :-/

Comment: Very well, let me wander off to a location I haven't been to and I'll get back to you!

Comment: I have encountered "respawns" in some areas. When you did your test, were the "level 10s" new to that area? In other words, are newly spawned Raiders (etc) also fixed at the level when you entered, or are they scaled up (within any parameters Fenixp spoke about)

Comment: Do legendaries follow normal spawning rules? I would be interested in information on non-legendary spawns showing up at your level.

Comment: I haven't seen any evidence of my level affecting the monster's levels in my play time. It might simply be that Legendary enemies are based on your level.