# What level is Father Gabe?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm doing a Survival play through of Fallout 4. I entered Union's Hope Cathedral outside of Cambridge (which I somehow managed to miss in all 1200 hours of prior game play), and encountered a named ghoul "Father Gabe".

I'm level 29, and am rather cautious about attacking much higher level enemies (with the 'skull' icon) in this go-through because I'm still not too good at finding beds in the wasteland to sleep and create a save point. When I run into a higher level enemy, I make note of the location and run away, then come back when I'm a more appropriate level.

Father Gabe shows as being much higher than me. I'm trying to figure out what his level is. Usually when this happens, I go to the Fallout wiki and check what level the NPC is -- but according to the [wiki](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Gabe_(Fallout_4)) Father Gabe is only level 1. I'm not finding any other information about his level when googling about this -- just lots of rants about how he's hostile when he really shouldn't be.

What level is Father Gabe actually?

Comment: Is the game console an option?

Comment: Not in Survival.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fallout 4, **enemy levels scale with the player**. However, the enemy level for your game is determined when you [first enter an area](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242891/enemy-difficulty-scaling-in-fallout-4).

If you have already encountered Father Gabe, you can just **level up for a little** (or find better weapons and gear) **and then return to the area**, at which point he should still be the same level he was when you first met him, and therefore easier to dispatch. There also is [another way](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Gabe_(Fallout_4)#Other_interactions) to pacify him.

Note that you shouldn't turn this around and quickly access absolutely every area possible for an easy time, as this will negatively affect your game in the long run. Higher level enemies give more XP, which you need to level up to higher levels yourself.

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't true for named characters.

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, while this is my first encounter with Father Gabe, I've encountered Sully Mathis in all of my previous play throughs. Regardless of when I first meet him (level 5 on my earliest play through, level 75+ on my "evil raider character" play through), he's always level 30 after he turns raider. Similarly Absalom, while he does "scale" with the player level, he doesn't scale beyond level 50. (Though Absalom might be different since he's a scripted random encounter and not a fixed named character.) Similarly the mirelurk queen at the Castle seems to be always lvl 50.

Comment: Not all named characters are the same. Those important to the storyline (also, where you're not supposed to kill them) tend to have fixed high levels. I doubt Gabe would break the story line if dead, in fact he seems to be intended to be hostile to the player :)

Comment: You might be right. Unfortunately upon returning to the church, i found Father Gabe dead in front of the altar, so there's not much more investigation i can do with this specific npc.

Comment: In nomini zombii, et ghoulii, et mutantii sancti, amen :)